# Use cron to screencapture on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, screen-capture, cron

I want to set cron to capture the current desktop every hour:

```
screencapture -Cd -tjpg ~/Desktop/screen-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M"`.jpg
```

I tired [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/26956/use-cron-to-screen-capture-on-mac-os-x) but it seems doesn't work on Mountain Lion. I also tried Lingo but with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`cron` behaves a bit differently than a standard prompt, which is why it's not doing what you're expecting. There are two issues with the command as is:

- Because it doesn't parse the `PATH` environment variable the same was as the shell, `cron` doesn't know where `screencapture` is. You need to specify the full path, `/usr/sbin/screencapture`.
- As noted in the [crontab(5) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab), `cron` treats `%` as a newline character:

  > Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

  So you need to escape each `%` with a `\` to get your desired result.

This `crontab` entry will give you a screen capture every hour, on the hour:

```
0 * * * * /usr/sbin/screencapture -Cd -tjpg ~/Desktop/screen-`date +"\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M"`.jpg
```

#### Cron Error Logging

As an aside, if you're having issues with cron, check your system mail by running the `mail` command in Terminal. It's not very obvious, but by default `cron` sends error messages there that can provide a starting point to figuring out what's going wrong.